# Is there a conventional way of referencing a revision in subversion

Tags: svn

To refer to the trunk in a Subversion repository called project we would say `project/trunk`, a tag `project/tags/1.07` both as shorthand for `http://svn-server/project/trunk`

Is there a similar convention for revisions? Is it as simple as `project/123`?

We have many repositories, each containing one project - not one repository with lots of projects in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply say the revision number?:

- Revision 21334 of project on trunk.
- Revision 21334 of trunk/project.

Some places append the revision after an `@` sign in emails:

> trunk/project@21334

We use Jenkins, so we refer to the Jenkins build number and the Jenkins project name.

> Build #423 on project-trunk

Comment: I think `@` is the typical fashion as its even accepted in the format of certain args to the CLI client. Though when not specifying a repo path its common to use `r1234` for a revision in conversation.

Comment: The `trunk/project` syntax, is that when you have many projects in a single repo? I've clarified my question a bit.

Comment: The `@` is used to _pin_ the URL to a particular release -- that is, the way the directories and files are laid out. The `-r` is used to specify a release. I take it that the OP was asking for a *shorthand* way of referring to a revision. The `@` is used in `svn:externals` to pin the external to a particular revision, and sites do use it as a shorthand to talk about a particular project at a particular revision (like when development is telling QA what revision they can test).

Comment: @DavidW. - essentially you're saying "no, there's no standard conventions, here are some suggestions", is that correct? I'll give it a couple more days and if no one else comes up with something more definitive then I'll accept.

Comment: Yes, there are really aren't any standard conventions. However, if I used the trunk/project@1234, most developers will understand exactly what I am talking about even if they haven't seen that used before. The `@` is used in Subversion to refer to the structure of a repo at a particular revision, so it's not unknown. It doesn't really refer to the revision itself.